# Wikidata SPARQL query that returns date a particular property was last edited on queried items

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

Let's say I'm looking for Wikidata cats who have their place of birth (P19) listed, using this query (also at https://w.wiki/5mdp):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?placeofbirthLabel ?date
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146;
        wdt:P19 ?placeofbirth;
        schema:dateModified ?date.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

This retrieves: item id, item label, (the label of) the place of birth, and the date that any part of the item was last updated.

**What if I also want to retrieve the date that the place of birth (P19) was last edited?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's possible per statement unless anything changed in the past, see also the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761025/retrieving-properties-last-updated-before-after-arbitrary-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place items can also have a `schema:dateModified` property:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?item_modified ?placeofbirthLabel ?placeofbirth_modified
WHERE 
{
  
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146 ;
        wdt:P19 ?placeofbirth ;
        schema:dateModified ?item_modified .
  
  ?placeofbirth schema:dateModified ?placeofbirth_modified .
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" . }
  
} LIMIT 10
```